# Set landscape orientation for fragment in Single Activity Architecture

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-orientation

How to achieve to lock screen orientation for only one `Fragment` **in Single Activity Architecture** (only one `Activity` for whole app)?

Is there better solution than specify requested orientation in each `Fragment`?
I'm trying to avoid putting `activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` to each unrelated `Fragment`

Comment: You can put `activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` in the fragment which need to have only a stable orientation. Others wise do not use any code and it should work as intended.

Comment: @RajeshK unfortunately the requested orientation will be used for all other fragments after visiting the changed one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let me start by saying that **@madlymad** has the right idea, and you should create a `BaseFragment` class if you haven't already.

However if for some reason you can't or don't want to, you can instead set the orientation in the `Fragment`'s `onAttached()`, `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

and then reset in their respective counterparts `onDetached()`, `onDestroy()` or `onDestroyView()`

```
activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
```

This will ensure that you only get different orientation in the correct fragment.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for the answer. `onCreateView()` / `onDestroyView()` is the right place to specify orientation, because `onAttached()` or `onCreate()` are not called in every fragment replacement.

Answer (score 3):

Add below line where you want to fragment in `Landscape` Mode:

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment 
            //ADD BELOW LINE
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

       return view;
    }
```

If you add above code in fragment then all fragment are show in `Landscape` mode. But You want to a single fragment. so in **Other Fragment add below code**

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            //ADD BELOW LINE
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory, container, false);


            return view;
        }
```

Note: No need to add Orientation in `manifest.xml`

Answer (score 2):

I would extend the `Fragment` and create a `BaseFragment` for all my fragments. At this base fragment I would use the `activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR`

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if(a != null)
             a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        }
    }
}
```

For the specific locked fragment I would just use the `activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE`.

```
public class LandscapeFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
            Activity a = getActivity();
            if(a != null)
             a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
}
```

The only change you would now have is to make all your fragments extend the `BaseFragment` instead of `Fragment`, but this can be beneficial in other shared features as well.

---

I am not familiar with Kotlin but Kotlin code may be like this:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
  override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser : Boolean){
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
     if(isVisibleToUser) {
       getActivity()?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR)    
     }
  }
}

class LandscapeFragment : BaseFragment() {
    override fun setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser : Boolean) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if(isVisibleToUser) {
             getActivity()?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is activity you can specify in manifest file only for activity tag.

In case for fragment in activity means i guess you can you below code

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

in activity i.e write a method by passing boolean if true PORTRAIT else LANDSCAPE and call it from fragment. I mean if the activity contains different fragments which requires different orientations.

Comment: My question is for Single Activity Architecture, so tag for activity in Manifest will change it for whole application. I'm trying to avoid putting `activity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED` to each unrelated `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Orientation attribute is per activity so you can declare the orientation for only the activity that contains the fragment so that it is in landscape and the rest of the activities will remain as they are.

**Use the following code line in the fragment where you want a specific (in this case portrait) orientation.**

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**If you want to have an orientation in a fragment, that is based on the way the user holds his device, then use the following code line.**

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
    android:name=".user_interface.activities.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"/>
```

Comment: this will change orientation for whole app (in single activity architecture), my question is about way to change orientation for specific fragment only

Comment: you can do this in frangment please try this 
 

getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

Comment: the change will stay for all other fragments. I need it for one only (looking for any other solution than define it in each fragment).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenarios as yours, I call all my fragments from my Activity. Which way i can have the code in one place.

```
    int id = item.getFragmentId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }
    // Here you can have your fragment calls
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
           R.id.content_main,
           new YourFragmentForId(),
           NotificationFragment.class.getSimpleName())
          .commit();
```

I still think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thank you rot your answer. But I use Navigation component (from Jetpack) instead of `FragmentManager`