# How can I make my navigation component support both portrait and landscape in fragment android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, orientation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am developing news app and i am using navigation components have only one fragment I want to make app should support both portrait and landscape  how can implement following logic in my app if app portrait orientation must be set portrait if it is landcape it has to set to landscape

below my BBCNewsFragment.kt

```
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.yodgorbek.newstask.databinding.BbcnewsFragmentBinding
import com.yodgorbek.newstask.model.Article
import com.yodgorbek.newstask.presentation.adapter.NewsAdapter
import com.yodgorbek.newstask.presentation.viewmodel.BBCNewsViewModel
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel

class BBCNewsFragment : Fragment() {


    private var _binding: BbcnewsFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding: BbcnewsFragmentBinding
        get() = _binding ?: throw NullPointerException("View wasn't created")

    private val viewModel by viewModel<BBCNewsViewModel>()
    private val adapter = NewsAdapter()


    // with the backing property of the kotlin we extract
    // the non null value of the _binding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        //ADD BELOW LINE
        getActivity()?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        getActivity()?.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        _binding = BbcnewsFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Add adapter in recyclerView
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        // listening new data
        viewModel.news.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { response ->


            adapter.differ.submitList(response.articles as MutableList<Article>)
        }

        viewModel.progress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { showLoading ->
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = showLoading
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710304/set-landscape-orientation-for-fragment-in-single-activity-architecture/53864286

Comment: You just need to make sure you have not specified screenOrientation attribute in activity tag of parent activity on this fragment inside AndroidManifest. Activity will automatically change orientation according to device orientation.

Comment: Also to handle any changes when configuration is changed just override onConfigurationChanged