# How do I allow only one specific fragment to have both portrait and landscape orientations in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-orientation

In my Android application, I have added `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to all activities in my `Android.manifest` and `android:orientation="vertical"` to every activity's/fragment's respective layout so that the app can only be viewed in portrait mode.

However, there is one fragment in particular that I want to enable both portrait and landscape orientations. This fragment extends the `DialogFragment()` class as it's a full-screen fragment. This fragment is contained within another fragment, so it uses `childFragmentManager` to be displayed.

How do I enable both portrait and landscape orientations for a specific fragment, while only enabling portrait orientation for the rest of my activities and fragments?

Comment: "and `android:orientation="vertical"` to every activity's/fragment's respective layout so that the app can only be viewed in portrait mode" -- note that `android:orientation` is a `LinearLayout` property and does not work for other common containers, like `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: "How do I enable both portrait and landscape orientations for a specific fragment" -- that is not an option. You can call `setRequestedOrientation()` on the `Activity` that hosts the fragment to try to undo your `android:screenOrientation` value when you show this fragment, though I have never tried that. Or, have this bit of UI be shown by a separate activity, one with the desired `android:screenOrientation` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864286/15351040

Just change the rotation type to Sensor or User, and reset when the fragment is destroyed or paused.